# Handling server failure using serialization

Tags: java

In my program, there is a central server, and I want to store its state. I'm using serialization for this, I am serializing the data after every 2,3 seconds. So that whenever server fails, it can come back and start from that point where it left.

The problem is that when server goes down, while serialization is in progress, streams are still open, so that obtained is corrupt, and is of no use. So when server goes down in that particular duration, it fails to recover. When it goes down, when serialization is not going on, it recovers and we obtain updated data.

So what can I do to make it work, no matter when it goes down?
I'm using java btw.

Comment: Are you serializing to a file and overwriting it? Try to write to 2 different files one each time. When recovering try to recover from the oldest one, if it does not work, then recover from the previous one.

Comment: What are you serializing to? There's different approaches for searlizing to disk or database or object cache.

Comment: you need to think about ACID http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID